# How do I can use a database with Espresso?

Tags: android, tdd, android-espresso

I am testing my application using Espresso.

My application uses a communication service to download the database on first access, but I can not do it when the tests are running.

My suggestion on this is to create a database with the data I need for application to run correctly.

Well, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide more information about your environment. Why can't you download the database on tests? If your app is able to download it normally, and put into a database, why don't you just use that to create fake data for the tests?

We have an application that we test using espresso, that uses the ActiveAndroid ORM http://www.activeandroid.com/. But basically you don't need it, you can use sqlite the same way you do right now.

Espresso should let you use everything you normally use in your app. You can download the database using http, or whatever, and you can also create a fake database.

If the download is slow, I would recommend you to initialize a fake database. Just create fake data depending on the needs of each test case, and fill it up before creating the first activity.

Comment: You're right. I downloaded the database when I'm testing :)
I did not know that Espresso uses normally the app. Thanks